# How to get specific values using String

Tags: java

I am creating a program that converts dates from numerical month-day format to alphabetic month-day format. I am stuck when I try to read in the user inputted data. For example, if the user enters the date 1/31, it should print out January 31, that works fine, but if I enter the date 14/23, it still prints out January 23, it should be invalid. This is the code I used to get the values. I am sure that I'm not supposed to use substring to get the values. That is why it is not working correctly. How would I approach this?

```
public static void readInput()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a date in numerical format, ex: 1/31");
    getDate = keyboard.nextLine();
    conversion();
}
public static void conversion()
{
    month = getDate.substring(0,1); // gets the month
    day = getDate.substring(2,4); // gets the date
    monthConversion();
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for `monthConversion()`?

Comment: You can't always assume that `month` fits into 1 character - you can use `String[] parts = getDate.split("/")` to split on the slash, and then get `month` from `parts[0]` and `day` from `parts[1]`.

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd").parse(String)`

Comment: You only get one character for `month`. This would give you the first 1 in "14/23"

Comment: A few tips: 1) Using `static` methods is often considered bad in Java because you are not using Object Oriented Programming. 2) Each method should do one thing. For example `readInput()` should only read the input and return it. This allows some other method the chance to decide what to do with that input. 3) Following with the previous suggestion, `conversion()` should take a String parameter that should be converted. This means that `conversion()` no longer relies on a global variable. It can also return the final result of the conversion.

Comment: 4) Learn how to use a debugger. All modern IDEs have this feature built in. It allows you to execute each line of code in your program one step at a time. As you do this, you can also view the values of variables at each moment to see if they are what you expect or not.

Comment: OK I got it I used String [] parts = getDate.split("/"); Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that since you split the input date by indexes, you don't handle the fact that each part can be 1 digit or 2 (1/1 is January the 1st, 10/10 is November the 10th).
You should consider splitting the input date around `/` with `getDate.split('/')` ; this will return an array whose first element will be the day part and second element will be the month part.

On a side note you should validate that you're actually getting the expected date format. Make sure both the expected parts are integers that could be day or month numbers, and that there is no extra part.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `substring(0,1)`. You need to do `substring(0,2)`

The other way is that you can take the input of month in the format of "mm" ie 01, 02, 12, etc and then apply `substring(0,2)`.

I hope this answers your question.